# mfabrik web and mobile installation

Tags: mobile, web, plone

I'm following the installation procedure for mfabrik's Web and Mobile and got stuck:

root@u10:/plone4/zinstance/gomobile# python bootstrap.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 97, in 
    pythonpath = ws.find(pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(requirement)).location
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Helio

Comment: Which Python version are you using? OS is Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx, Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56). Is Ida a female name? If so, Herzlich Glukwunsche fur die "International Women's Day"!

Answer (score 0):

I found that to solve that error I had to install the 'distribute' package.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

So, that problem is solved ... and I'm struggling with the ones that came up after that one.

Regards,
Helio